# How do I add /lang to the Wordpress homepage url?

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink, permalinks

How do I add a `/lang` to the home url of a Wordpress site? I've got a project with a special Wordpress multisite setup instead of a language plugin setup. I need to be able to set the homepage to `www.homepage.com/lang-1` without always having the `/lang-1` in every url.

I've tried doing this via permalinks but Wordpress redirects to the link without `/lang-1`. Is there a way to fix this? I know how to change the home page but I want to change the link to the home page.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you need the final result to be. What would help would be a series of example URLs, and in which circumstances you want and expect to see them. I was going to suggest exactly the same as Ajesh VC did.

Answer (score 0):

To set the home page with custom page

1. Click on Settings >> Reading in your admin dashboard.
2. Set Your homepage displays to A static page (2nd option)
3. Select the static page we created (lang-1) as the Homepage

4 .Click Save.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need the homelink to change aswel by doing this you still have the homepage link without /lang-1.